# mediaelementjs PAUSE other players

Tags: mp3, mediaelement.js, mediaelement, audio-player

I have multiple mediaelement audio mp3 players on my website and even though "pauseOtherPlayers:!0" is present in the mediaelement-and-player.min.js file the other players still don't pause when another begins.

Do I need to add the

```
pauseOtherPlayers:!0
```

element to the embedded html code? Or do I need to change it to

```
pauseOtherPlayers: true
```

in order for it to work?

Thanks so much for your reply!

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/6x37m6j2/ when you play a sound, the others pause automatically, does this work for you?

Comment: It appears to work in the link you provided but I'm not sure how to tell what's missing in my code?

Comment: Me neither is I cannot see your code